# Triangles counted in triangulation of projective plane

Tags: general-topology

Why isn't, for example, the triangle 123 counted? There is clearly a loop from 1 to 2 to 3 to 1 so I don't see why it's not counted. Similarly, other triangles such as 125 are not counted.

The only triangles counted are the ones explicitly forming a 3-sided shape in the picture. Why is this the case?

This is the image I'm referring to:[image]

In general I'm confused as to how to show a triangulation actually is a triangulation, especially when the shape isn't easily visualized in 3 dimensions. Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the $1$-simplices $(1,2), (2,3), (3,1)$ form a loop in the projective plane. However, they do not bound a triangle, i.e. a $2$-simplex. A simpler example is this.  In figure 1.13 take the complex consisting of the vertices $4, 5, 6$ and the $1$-simplices  $(4,5), (5,6), (6,4)$. The $2$-simplex $(4,5,6)$ does not belong to this complex.

Comment: So it's by construction that it is not a 2-simplex, not because of any inherent properties. Adding this triangle would still be a valid triangulation of the projective plane, correct?

Comment: No, if you add this triangle, you get another space. I guess you know the concept of the fundamental group of a space. The loop from $1$ to $2$ to $3$ is a nontrivial element of the fundamental group of the projective plane, but if you the triangle, this loop becomes inessential which shows that the bigger space is not even homotopy equivalent to the  projective plane.